# How do I rename a folder to project name in a Visual Studio template?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015

I have created a new Visual Studio template and am wanting one of the folders to rename to the project name automatically when it is created. I have tried editing the template file and project file as described in some material but this has not worked. Any ideas?

```
<Folder Name="Views" TargetFolderName="Views">
    <Folder Name="Template" TargetFolderName="$safeprojectname$">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Index.cshtml">Index.cshtml</ProjectItem>
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Index.generated.cs">Index.generated.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Folder>
</Folder>
```

This is what I have tried in the template file.

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to figure it out!... Instead of creating the "Template" folder I wanted to rename in the project, I deleted this and placed the files that were within that folder ("Index.cshtml" and "Index.generated.cs") in the root of the project.

After this I exported the project as a template. In the template file, I created the folders I wanted (with the names I wanted) by changing the target file name as below:

```
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Views\$safeprojectname$\Index.cshtml">Index.cshtml</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Views\$safeprojectname$\Index.generated.cs">Index.generated.cs</ProjectItem>
```

Then in the project file I changed any references to the two files to look for "Views\$safeprojectname$\Index.cshtml" and "Views\$safeprojectname$\Index.generated.cs" as opposed to just looking for the files in the root.

Voila!

Comment: having `$safeprojectname$` in the `TargetFileName` did NOT work for me. I get an error when creating a new solution. The file does not exists. Although the syntax seems to be correct based on Microsoft docs.